# Php Class not Found (Zend)

Tags: php, class, zend-framework

I am getting an error `Php Class not Found (Zend)`

My Folder Hierarchy :

```
/FFMobile(main Folder)
    /Controller(Folder)
    /Model(Folder)
         /Tournament.php
    /class1.php
         /method1();
    /class2.php
         /method2();
```

My goad is to access Class1 and class2 in Tournament.php

ATM I am trying to access them in a following way

```
$data1 = /class1::method1();
$data2 = /class2::method2();
```

but I am not able to access the classes I am getting error message `"Class not Found".`

Comment: Your slashes are wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you required those class in you Tournament.php ?

You can do it with the `use` command.

Moreover I suggest not using the scope operator `::` only to call 1 method, we usually do that when we want to call a parent::method.

You should instantiate de class and then call the method.

```
$class1 = new \class1();
$data1 = $class1->method1();
$class2 = new \class2();
$data2 = $class2->method2();
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: I have done that with giving namespace to the class1.php and directly use that at the Tournament.php like \FFMobile\Class1::method1(); its working